# What's the exact difference b\w homekit & external accessory framework?

Tags: ios8, healthkit, external-accessory, homekit

I am new to ios,and i have a doubt that whether implementation of homekit/healthkit frameworks needs the involvement of the external accessory framework.
         I mean with the homekit/healthkit framework whether we can directly communicate with the MFi devices,with out the involvement of external accessory framework??. 
......pls do guide.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Homekit Framework used to communicate between HAP (Homekit Accessory protocol) enabled accessory and iOS device. Like Lightbulb, Door lock, Bridge (which further connects to zigbee/zwave devices).

External Accessory framework used to communicate with external hardware/device using dock connector or bluetooth. Like Heartrate monitor, Smart Thermometer etc.

iOS application can connect to HAP enabled device which has implemented MFi authentication using Homekit framework. There's no need to include/use external accessory framework.

However if HAP Accessory(bridge/Garage door) has wifi, then iOS app requires to use External accessory framework.

For Healthkit, to connect with external accessory (Like, Heart rate monitor) which generally has bluetooth / dock connector you may require to use External Accessory framework.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I have a doubt on your 3rd point ( iOS application can connect to HAP enabled device which has implemented MFi authentication using Homekit framework. There's no need to include/use external accessory framework.). In this case by what means of communication will the iOS device will communicate with the HAP device.And why we dont need External Accessory frame work here?? and why we need it if it has wifi support??

Comment: For 3rd : iOS app connects to HAP enabled device using Bonjour in network. These accessories doesn't require external frame work as they are connected  in intranet (Accessory like bridge connected with Ethernet cabel to home's intranet work.) So iOS app will automatically discover that accessory. If it is wifi accessory then it requires setup (Like every other wifi we are using to access internet) once its configured it can connect to that accessory.

Comment: If i understood your answer properly,( Your ans:"These accessories doesn't require externalframe work as they are connected in intranet" )..Are the ios device and accessory get connected with each other by means of lightning cable(wired connection) ??? Is this what you are trying to say..??

Comment: No, not like that. Actually iOS device should connect to normal wifi router which is further connected to Accessory (bridge) using ethernet cabel. So iOS Application can able to connect to accessory in intranet mode.

Comment: So the accessories which doesnt have a inbuit wifi chip in it (non-wifi accessory)....can nly be connected through ethernet....And these devices can be contacted by ios devices without the help of external accessory framework ?? am i rite samir ??

Comment: 1) Thats True for non-wifi and enthernet enabled accessories (mostly they are bridge). 2) non-wifi accessories can have zigbee or zwave radio which can connect to bridge accessory. 3) There are many non-wifi accessories which can directly connected to iOS app using Bluetooth like door lock.